# Python (pandas) loop through values in a column, do a calc with each value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set of dB values in a dataframe and want to do a calc for each row in a specific column. I've tried this:

```
for i in dataAnti['antilog']:
    x = 10**(i/10)
```

It gives me the correct value but only loops once. How do I save these new values in a new column or save over the values in the antilog column?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to define the new column and simply formulate the calculus you desire.

```
dataAnti['new_column'] = 10**(dataAnti['antilog']/10)
```

This will automatically take the value of each row and perform the calculation to assign the resulting value to the same row in the `new_column`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the apply attribute.

```
dataAnti['result']=dataAnti['antilog'].apply(lambda i: 10**(i/10))
```

You can pass any function inside apply() that takes an input and applies the result to each column.